# Physical back button not working in Flutter, I can't even exit the app

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have no clue why this is happening. When device or emulator back button is pressed, nothing happens. App bar back button is working!, implemented back button works also.

I've created a new flutter project to test this problem:

**First page**

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: FlatButton(
      color: Colors.grey[300],
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => NextPage(),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Text('next page'),
    ),
  ),
);
```

**Second page**

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('next page'),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: FlatButton(
      color: Colors.grey[300],
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      child: Text('go back'),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Did you tried in real Device?

Comment: yes, both emulator and a physical device, same issue :(

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code and it's working fine for me. Can you provide the full code?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. i updated to the latest version of flutter master channel and then this issue occured.

Answer (score 1):

I used to be on master channel, I upgraded flutter today, and this issue came up.
The solution was to change the channel to stable.

**Run the command**

```
Flutter channel stable
```

**After it finishes run**

```
Flutter clean
```

and everything should be alright.

Comment: Back button stops working after routing a few times (`WillPopScope`, returning to previous route and exiting app) on `Flutter 1.22.0-10.0.pre.82 • channel master`, switching to `Flutter 1.20.3 • channel stable` fixed the issue.